# Como fazer a validação do login sem redirecionar a página?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho o seguinte formulário de login em um dropdown, minha dúvida é o seguinte, como fazer a validação do login sem redirecionar a página?

Atualmente quando o usuário informa uma senha errada ele é redirecionado a pagina de login e informa a mensagem de erro.

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Login via
            <div class="social-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
            </div>
            or
            <form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required value="{{ old('email') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>


            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
                <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forget the password ?</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                </button>
            </div>
            {{-- <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                </label>
            </div> --}}
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom text-center">
            Novo por aqui ? <a href="{{ url('/register') }}"><b>Registre-se</b></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Se estiver usando o `Laravel 5`, é bom nos informar. Talvez você esteja utilizando o `AuthController`. Se for o caso, talvez seja necessário apenas configurar a variável $redirectTo para  a página desejada

Comment: Ou então, faça o login via ajax.

Comment: Sim estou usando Laravel 5.2 e `AuthController`

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá. Creio que a melhor solução no seu caso para não redirecionar a página caso haja um erro de autenticação é utilizar o ajax, pois pelo que entendi você está usando um dropdown.

Você pode fazer com que seu formulário envia as informações presentes no formulário do login da seguinte forma:

```
$('#login-nav').submit(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        url: '/auth/login-ajax',

        success: function (response)
        {
            if (! response.isLogged)
            {
                // ação quando login é inválido

                return;
            }

            // Ação para quando o cara logar
        }
    })
})
```

Crie o método no `AuthController` para fazer a verificação do login via ajax:

```
public function postLoginAjax(Request $request)
{
    $isLogged = auth()->attempt([
        'email'    => $request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->get('senha')
    ]);        


    return response()->json(['isLogged' => $isLogged]);
}
```

Não esqueça de registra o método no `routes.php`

```
Route::post('/auth/login-ajax', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLoginAjax']);
```